# Go to next page depending on multiple answers – Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I've tried to create a Google Form with Google Apps Script without success.

My goal is to redirect to a new page depending on the results of multiple answers, not just one. I've got three questions and if some of them has a specific answer I've would like to go to another page.

It seems like its possible just for one question like this:

```
var choiceOne = item.createChoice('Vanilla', FormApp.PageNavigationType.CONTINUE);
var choiceTwo = item.createChoice('Chocolate', FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT);
```

Is it a way to solve the problem?

Comment: Not possible with Google Forms. You must write your own HTML form (or find some other form provider that allows what you want).

Comment: Ok, so sad. Thanks for your response!